# Inner Class to Create a "value object" (VO) Object

Tags: java

is it a bad practice to use a inner class as a VO so the code can be clear

EX:
I have to modify some values before storing the data in a file. I have created a VO Class so that If someone else needs to modify it in future , it could be easily readable.

This process of operation will be performed only in this class and the VO that I generated will not be used in any place else. So In that case is it better to create a inner Class and use it ? would it be  bad practice to do something like that ? would creating inner class and using them as VO cause any security concerns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing visibility is a good thing in general.

But you can also achieve this by putting the VO in a separate file in the same package folder making the class (and its methods) *package private*. With respect to UnitTest for your business logic this might be the better approach.

Comment: @Kaiizok *"is it wrong to use the inner class as VO ?"* as usual there is no clear right or wrong. But defining the DTO as an inner class forces an additional dependency to the "outer" class for the user of the DTO. This might not be useful in some cases...